# Create one PDF map of large extent from serval 1:50000 scale sections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to produce a single PDF map that shows an entire property via several 1:50,000 scale maps stitched together. The scale is important to show the labelled information correctly within my polygons but the property is very large and requires several separate "windows" of 50,000 scale.

Is there a way to export a larger map extent in several 50,000 scale sized portions that are all stitched together. The atlas tool does not seem to accomplish exactly what I am looking for as it bases its separate pages on a polygon feature not on the scale + enlarged canvas extent the way I need it to.

I am utilizing up to date QGIS software.